# Is asking for a comparison between/survey of libraries on topic?

Tags: discussion, recommendation-questions

I know that asking for library recommendation is off-topic on the site. However, many such questions could easily be reworded as just a survey and/or comparison of the currently available libraries for a specific problem.

For example, you can eliminate the "recommendation" part of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9761507/939108), by writing something like this:

> There are many pretty-printing libraries in Haskell. For example:
>
> - pretty
> - prettyprinter
> - wl-pprint
>
> What are the main differences and use cases for these libraries?

These kinds of questions can be very useful and often attract high-quality answers. For example, the by far most popular and highest voted [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5767129/939108) (and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5769285/939108)) about ["haskell lenses"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell+lenses?sort=votes&pageSize=10) is asking for a library recommendation in the title but in the question body it asks for a comparison.

---

So, is asking such questions in general on topic? And is rewording old questions like this to be less subjective a good idea?

Deciding which library to use is a difficult problem and having a basic shallow survey of the field can be very useful.

Comment: The example question is from 2011, the rules as to what is on/off-topic might have been different back then. Probably not in this specific case, but it is something to keep in mind when making comparisons.

Comment: 'having a basic shallow survey of the field can be very useful' indeed.  I suggest you perform one whenever you need to pick a library for some purpose.

Answer (score 14):

No, questions like that are generally too broad, or even opinion based.

As the "Too broad" close-vote reason says:

> Please edit the question to **limit it to a specific problem** with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

*(Emphasis mine)*

Comment: I often find myself wanting to know the main differences between libraries without limiting myself to a specific problem. Like "what is the purposes of libraries X and Y? What problems are they intended to solve?" This does not feel like a very broad question. You don't need much depth for such a comparison to be useful.

Comment: _"what is the purposes of library X"_ is best answered by visiting said library's site. Stack Overflow simply is not the place for questions like that.

Comment: Why not? What is the place for questions like that?

Comment: Quora, maybe? I'm pretty sure there isn't a Stack exchange site for questions like that.